# MySQL SELECT - Switch Row With Column

Tags: mysql, select, union, pivot-table

I apologize for the lack of explanation on the title, as I do not know what to really call what I am trying to do, please modify if you know what I am looking for.

Here is my current table:

```
prodID | seller  |  price
123      seller1    5000
123      seller2    3000
123      seller3    5500
123      seller4    3500
500      seller2    55
500      seller5    60
200      seller1    35
200      seller2    25
200      seller3    35
```

Now I want to `GROUP BY` prodID above and list each column as a the sellers price which could potentially be `NULL`, ie:

```
prodID  | seller1 | seller2 | seller3 | seller4 | seller5
123       5000      3000      5500      3500      null
500       null      55        null      null      60
200       35        25        35        null      null
```

I do not know how many unique sellers there are, so think of them as dynamic and not fixed.

I dont think I need a `PIVOT TABLE` from what I have been researching, but please correct me if wrong.  I have also tried a `UNION` and combining the same table, but this seems inefficient as I dont know how many sellers there are and what their names are:

**Inefficient:**

```
SELECT 
    MT.prodID, MT.price, CT.price
from
    `table` MT,
    `table` CT
WHERE
    MT.prodID = CT.prodID
        AND MT.seller != CT.seller
GROUP BY MT.prodID
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you aren't trying to do a `PIVOT TABLE` and can't do this in another programming language (which would be the best options for this)... something you can do is this.

```
SELECT 
    t.prodID, 
    t1.seller1, 
    t.seller2, 
    t2.seller3, 
    t3.seller4, 
    t4.seller5 
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        m1.prodID, m1.price AS seller2
    FROM myTable AS m1
    WHERE m1.seller LIKE "seller2"
) AS t

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        m.prodID,
        m.price AS seller1
    FROM myTable AS m
    WHERE m.seller LIKE "seller1"
) AS t1 ON t.prodID = t1.prodID

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        m2.prodID, 
        m2.price AS seller3
    FROM myTable AS m2
    WHERE m2.seller LIKE "seller3"
) AS t2 ON t2.prodID = t.prodID

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        m3.prodID, 
        m3.price AS seller4
    FROM myTable AS m3
    WHERE m3.seller LIKE "seller4"
) AS t3 ON t3.prodID = t.prodID

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        m4.prodID, 
        m4.price AS seller5
    FROM myTable AS m4
    WHERE m4.seller LIKE "seller5"
) AS t4 ON t4.prodID = t.prodID
```

this is kinda a hacky way to do it, but it transposes your data per your request. see the sql fiddle for results... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55f59/45

Comment: I like this idea, though its not the best way because of my dynamic sellers (currently 108).  I am willing to do a `PIVOT TABLE`, I just didn't know one can be done with Procedures because of my dynamic sellers.

Comment: really you should do this in another programming language... I don't know which one your using.. but you can easily transpose all of the data with a few lines of code in a different programming language